# How to get cumulative max records from the table without using OLAP function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below

```
   -------------------------------------
   | Id | startdate | enddate    |rate|
   -------------------------------------
   | 1  | 1/1/2015  | 2/1/2015   | 10 |
   | 1  | 2/1/2015  | 3/1/2015   | 15 | 
   | 1  | 3/1/2015  | 4/1/2015   | 5  |
   | 1  | 4/1/2015  | 5/1/2015   | 10 |
   | 1  | 5/1/2015  | 6/1/2015   | 20 |
   | 1  | 6/1/2015  | 7/1/2015   | 30 |
   | 1  | 7/1/2015  | 8/1/2015   | 10 |
   | 1  | 8/1/2015  | 9/1/2015   | 30 |
   | 1  | 9/1/2015  | 12/31/2015 | 20 |
   ------------------------------------
```

I need to populate cumulative max values for each id (Id=1 for this example) including the first record, like below (SQL server 2008):

```
   ----------------------------------
   | Id | startdate | enddate  |rate |
   ----------------------------------
   | 1  | 1/1/2015  | 2/1/2015 | 10  |
   | 1  | 2/1/2015  | 3/1/2015 | 15  |
   | 1  | 5/1/2015  | 6/1/2015 | 20  |
   | 1  | 6/1/2015  | 7/1/2015 | 30  |
   | 1  | 8/1/2015  | 9/1/2015 | 30  |
   -----------------------------------
```

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the cumulative max in SQL Server 2008 using outer apply:

```
select t.*, t2.maxrate
from t outer apply
     (select max(t2.rate) as maxrate
      from t t2
      where t2.startdate <= t.startdate
     ) t2;
```

Your question appears to be about filtering, not just calculating the cumulative maximum value.  You can select the rows with the max rate using a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, t2.maxrate
      from t outer apply
           (select max(t2.rate) as maxrate
            from t t2
            where t2.startdate <= t.startdate
           ) t2
     ) t
where t.rate = t.maxrate;
```

This will return duplicates in a row.  A better way is to use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.rate > t.rate and t2.startdate < t.startdate
                 );
```